# How can I find a lost dog in Minecraft Ps4

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

Recently my brother lost his dog in minecraft. I feel bad for him because he treated the dog like it was real. I hope someone can help and I can't use commands because I'm on PlayStation.

Comment: Why can you not use commands? They exist on console.

Comment: Well I can't can use the / something command

Comment: @FabianRöling Commands don't exist in Legacy Console Edition.